# Adding MultiBinding and Binding to Resources collection

Tags: wpf

Why is it not possible?

I use the same binding in a lot of places and I hate to copy and paste the same xaml instead of use it as a resource...

any way to to this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your bindings within a style which can reside as a resource.

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle">
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <MultiBinding
        Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" >
        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
          <Binding.../>
          <Binding.../>
        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
     </MultiBinding>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: But this cannot be assigned to a Trigger's setter, since a Trigger doesn't support styling. Is there any way to do that? Thank you!